# FtpWebRequest request is triggering a Invalid URI format

Tags: exception, uri, ftpwebrequest

From the command line I can successfully connect via FTP to my host using either

```
ftp.domain.com or domain.com

C:\Users\Aaron>ftp
ftp> open
To domain.com
Connected to domain.com.
220 FTP Server ready.
User (domain.com:(none)): Login failed.
ftp> close
221 Goodbye.
ftp> open
To ftp.domain.com
Connected to ftp.domain.com.
220 FTP Server ready.
User (ftp.domain.com:(none)): Login failed.
ftp> close
221 Goodbye.
ftp> quit
```

I escaped entering the password above and scrubbed the domain, but it still shows for each connection I was successful.  When I run this code in Visual studio, I get the invalid URI.

Here is my code I've tried in C#

```
Uri target = new Uri("ftp://ftp.domain.com/");
FtpWebRequest requestDir = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(target);
requestDir.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");

Uri target = new Uri("ftp://ftp.domain.com/");
FtpWebRequest requestDir = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(target);
requestDir.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
```

The requested URI is invalid for this FTP command

I've looked on here as there are many like this, but I've tried all of them (I think) and I just keep on getting this error.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working with the help of some other posts here and a lot of troubleshooting.  I now have this working and have moved on to new errors.  Here is the code for the successful FTP upload:

```
reqCakes = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://domain.com/images/" + "koala.jpg");
                reqCakes.UseBinary = true;
                reqCakes.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                reqCakes.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
                BinaryReader rdrCakes = new BinaryReader(File.Open(fileToOpen, FileMode.Open));
                rdrCakes.Close();
                byte[] cakeData = File.ReadAllBytes(fileToOpen);
                reqCakes.ContentLength = cakeData.Length;
                Stream reqStream = reqCakes.GetRequestStream();
                reqStream.Write(cakeData, 0, cakeData.Length);
                reqStream.Close();
```